# Flash, PHP MySQL...I can't seem to retrieve more than one column of data

Tags: php, mysql, flash, adobe

I am learning Flash, PHP and MySQL at the same time and of course it's become an issue. Through tutorials and from scratch code building I've been able to get my custom built Flash app to get a piece of data from my MySQl database. Here's the ActionScript:

```
gobtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, srchPeople);

function srchPeople(e:MouseEvent):void
{

// Assign a variable name for our URLVariables object
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

// Build the varSend variable
// Be sure you place the proper location reference to your PHP config file here
var varSend:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.myhost.com/my_php.php");
varSend.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
varSend.data = variables;

// Build the varLoader variable
var varLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;
varLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
varLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

variables.txtBox = txtBox.text;
variables.sendRequest = "parse";

// Send the data to the php file
varLoader.load(varSend);

// When the data comes back from PHP we display it here     
function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{   
    var phpVar1 = event.target.data.var1;
    //var phpVar2 = event.target.data.var2;

    testBox.text = phpVar1;
    testBox.alpha = 87;
    testBox.autoSize ="left";
    modalBox.alpha = 57;

    modalBox.height = testBox.height + 30;
    modalBox.width = testBox.width + 30;
}
}
```

Everything in the ActionScript does what it's suppose to. I POST the contents of txtBox to PHP and it is then fetched from the MySQL database and then displayed in testBox...but only one piece of information. I've experimented with the PHP and queries for hours trying to retrieve more than one column of information for that row. I am only calling one single variable as shown here in the PHP file:

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "mwh", "password"); 
mysql_select_db ("mydb");

// Only run this script if the sendRequest is from our flash application
if ($_POST['sendRequest'] == "parse") 
{
// Access the value of the dynamic text field variable sent from flash
$txtBox = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtBox']);

$query = "SELECT fname FROM People WHERE fname='$txtBox'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);
//$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$first_name = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($first_name == 0)
    //echo "Name does not exist.";
    print "var1 = $result doesn't exist.";
else
{
        $result = mysql_result($result, 0);
                    /// I've tried using other variables
        print "var1=$result has been retrieved from the database.";

}   


}
mysql_close();
?>
```

I understand that the  **SELECT** statement is only calling one variable. I've tried using others,  **lastname age address** etc, but was not able to retrieve it. I tried using the **SELECT *** with a while loop, but did not get the results. What am I missing? I tried using a **while** loop, along with another Flash based variable. Can't seem to figure this one out. All of the code that's posted DOES work, I'm just stuck on how to finish it to retrieve all of the column information in one row. All of the column data is to be displayed in **testBox.text** on the Flash form. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Screen capture of the returned data]

Comment: 1. don't use mysql_*() functions. they're deprecated. 2. you're vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). DO NOT USE THIS CODE.

Comment: Thanks. Will fix ASAP. Any suggestions on the question though?

Comment: Would take care of the injection? $txtBox = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['txtBox']);

Comment: better, but you really should be switching over to mysqli or PDO, using prepared statements. then you don't (almost) don't have to worry about injection problems.